# magento 1.9.2 - apply layer filter to custom product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, layered-navigation, product-collection

I want to apply layer navigation filter in custom product collection.

Ex:- http://domain.com/seller/collection/test/?**condition=new&brand=xyz**

Now I have collection of products of particular seller as per below code.

```
  $layer = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer');
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::app()-  >getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
  $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
  $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => '339,340,345,356'));
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(4)));

  $this->setCollection($collection);
```

**Now before set collection ($this->setCollection($collection)), I want to apply layered filter to collection as per query string.**

**Means apply condition and brand filter.**

Please help me as soon as possible. I have waste almost one day in this customization.

Or give me some alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code,

```
  $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();


  $layer = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer');
  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::app()-  >getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
  $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
  $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => '339,340,345,356'));
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(4)));

  if(count($params)){
      // Make sure array key is attribute code
      foreach($params as $key => $value) {
          $collection->addAttributeToFilter($key, array('eq' => $value));
      }
  }


  $this->setCollection($collection);
```

Comment: hey Thanks for the reply. But its dynamic string means multiple parameters there. So I want dynamic solution for the same.

Comment: Please check updated answer, hope it will help you. Thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks for quick replay and its work. But condition attribute type is dropdown and magento store option id in database for dropdown.
Can you please help me with dropdown attribute filtration?

Comment: You need to pass option_id of condition attribute to filter. Use same "addAttributeToFilter" it will work.